# On sets with positive density.

Tags: number-theory

I'm a prospective undergraduate student who is deeply passionate about number theory and i just came across the interesting concept of density of sets.

My question: If the set of integers $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ has positive density, does this imply that the set of integer solutions to $f(x)=0$ has zero density ?

Comment: A short answer is No. Try to find a function $f(x)$ such that both sets have positive density.

Comment: For examle, try $f(x)=x\mod 2$

Comment: Thank you very much @i1707107 and vrugtehagel , at least i have learnt something.